# Error when build nextjs in docker, but local it works

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, next.js

I can't build my nextjs app in docker, but localy it doesn't have any errors. I added in my nextjs config `output: 'standalone'`. I'm using yarn for whole project.

My Dockerfile is exactly this same like https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-docker/Dockerfile and dockerignore is this same as https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-docker/.dockerignore

Error:

```bash
#13 0.556 $ next build
#13 0.866 info  - Loaded env from /app/.env
#13 1.081 Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
#13 1.081 This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
#13 1.081 You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
#13 1.081 https://nextjs.org/telemetry
#13 1.081
#13 1.198 info  - Linting and checking validity of types...
#13 1.544 error - ESLint must be installed in order to run during builds: yarn add --dev eslint
#13 1.552 info  - Creating an optimized production build...
#13 10.49 info  - Compiled successfully
#13 10.49 info  - Collecting page data...
#13 11.45 node:internal/child_process/serialization:127
#13 11.45     const string = JSONStringify(message) + '\n';
#13 11.45                    ^
#13 11.45
#13 11.45 TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
#13 11.45     --> starting at object with constructor 'Socket'
#13 11.45     |     property '_httpMessage' -> object with constructor 'ClientRequest'
#13 11.45     --- property 'socket' closes the circle
#13 11.45     at stringify (<anonymous>)
#13 11.45     at writeChannelMessage (node:internal/child_process/serialization:127:20)
#13 11.45     at process.target._send (node:internal/child_process:839:17)
#13 11.45     at process.target.send (node:internal/child_process:739:19)
#13 11.45     at reportError (/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/jest-worker/processChild.js:1:1995)
#13 11.45     at reportClientError (/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/jest-worker/processChild.js:1:1671)
#13 11.45     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
#13 12.07 node:internal/child_process/serialization:127
#13 12.07     const string = JSONStringify(message) + '\n';
#13 12.07                    ^
#13 12.07
#13 12.07 TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
#13 12.07     --> starting at object with constructor 'Socket'
#13 12.07     |     property '_httpMessage' -> object with constructor 'ClientRequest'
#13 12.07     --- property 'socket' closes the circle
#13 12.07     at stringify (<anonymous>)
#13 12.07     at writeChannelMessage (node:internal/child_process/serialization:127:20)
#13 12.07     at process.target._send (node:internal/child_process:839:17)
#13 12.07     at process.target.send (node:internal/child_process:739:19)
#13 12.07     at reportError (/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/jest-worker/processChild.js:1:1995)
#13 12.07     at reportClientError (/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/jest-worker/processChild.js:1:1671)
#13 12.07     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
#13 12.67 node:internal/child_process/serialization:127
#13 12.67     const string = JSONStringify(message) + '\n';
#13 12.67                    ^
#13 12.67
#13 12.67 TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
#13 12.67     --> starting at object with constructor 'Socket'
#13 12.67     |     property '_httpMessage' -> object with constructor 'ClientRequest'
#13 12.67     --- property 'socket' closes the circle
#13 12.67     at stringify (<anonymous>)
#13 12.67     at writeChannelMessage (node:internal/child_process/serialization:127:20)
#13 12.67     at process.target._send (node:internal/child_process:839:17)
#13 12.67     at process.target.send (node:internal/child_process:739:19)
#13 12.67     at reportError (/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/jest-worker/processChild.js:1:1995)
#13 12.67     at reportClientError (/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/jest-worker/processChild.js:1:1671)
#13 12.67     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
#13 13.29 node:internal/child_process/serialization:127
#13 13.29     const string = JSONStringify(message) + '\n';
#13 13.29                    ^
#13 13.29
#13 13.29 TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
#13 13.29     --> starting at object with constructor 'Socket'
#13 13.29     |     property '_httpMessage' -> object with constructor 'ClientRequest'
#13 13.29     --- property 'socket' closes the circle
#13 13.29     at stringify (<anonymous>)
#13 13.29     at writeChannelMessage (node:internal/child_process/serialization:127:20)
#13 13.29     at process.target._send (node:internal/child_process:839:17)
#13 13.29     at process.target.send (node:internal/child_process:739:19)
#13 13.29     at reportError (/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/jest-worker/processChild.js:1:1995)
#13 13.29     at reportClientError (/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/jest-worker/processChild.js:1:1671)
#13 13.29     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
#13 13.30
#13 13.30 > Build error occurred
#13 13.31 Error: Call retries were exceeded
#13 13.31     at ChildProcessWorker.initialize (/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/jest-worker/index.js:1:11661)
#13 13.31     at ChildProcessWorker._onExit (/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/jest-worker/index.js:1:12599)
#13 13.31     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
#13 13.31     at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:475:12)
#13 13.31     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12) {
#13 13.31   type: 'WorkerError'
#13 13.31 }
#13 13.34 error Command failed with exit code 1.
#13 13.34 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c yarn build]: exit code: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a bug (mentioned [here](https://github.com/apify/got-scraping/issues/41) and [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/10577)) caused by circular references in `jest`. You could try one of the proposed [workarounds](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/10577#issuecomment-829562937) of using an older version of `jest` that isn't affected by this issue. Add the following to your `package.json`:

```
    "resolutions": {
        "jest-jasmine2": "26.0.1"
    }
```

Comment: I added it, but still, I have an error